# MongoDB: Advanced search algoritme with different multiple params

Tags: mongodb, search, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection with arround 300.000 documents, and I want to be able to do a text search, but with the ability to change the score based on some user params.

Example:

```
const query = 'love me';
const userLang = 'da-dk';

MusicCollection.find(
    {
      $text: { $search: `"${query}"` },
    },
    {
      fields: {
        score: { $meta: 'textScore' },
      },
      limit: 200,
      sort: {
        score: { $meta: 'textScore' },
      },
    },
  )
```

This works, and I get all matches with the string 'love me', but what if I want to up the search score for artist with a langCode: userLang ?

I just want artist from the users country to be prioritized and e.g. have added 20 point to the search score.

Is it possible to do this in one query? :)

Cheers
Peter

--- UPDATE ---
The documents follow this schema:

```
{
  _id: String,
  artist: String,
  title: String,
  albumId: String,
  genres: [String],
  langCode: String,
  description: String,
  rating: Number,
}
```

And I have created following index:

```
MusicCollection.createIndex(
 {
   genres: "text",
   artist: "text",
   title: "text",
   description: "text",
 },
 { 
   name: 'music_search',
   default_language: "english",
   weights: {
     genres: 5,
     artist: 15,
     title: 20,
     description: 10,
   }
 }
)
```

But what i want is to send the 'da-dk' user variable into the query, so all documents with the langCode: 'da-dk' would get a better score. Not said that I want ALL document with da-dk first, but just up the search score by 20 e.g.

Comment: How does you schema look?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is relevant, or maybe, I dont understand the question :) See changes above...